# AnyLogic Date format

Tags: date, anylogic

Is there a way to change the date format in AnyLogic, without constructing something with the implemented Time functions?

I want my Date to be displayed in such a way
"E dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"

With the timefunctions I have problems, to get the date into the right format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what that E stands for, but if it's the timezone, you can get it with this:

```
ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

I used Europe/Oslo there, but you can find the zone ids that you need here:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/wcs/tag-ref/MISC/TimeZones.html

to use this you need to import libraries in Main/Advanced Java/Imports section

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
```

And then to get the required code with that format:

```
"E "+String.format("%02d", getDayOfMonth())+"."
+String.format("%02d",getMonth()+1)+"."
+String.format("%04d",getYear())+" "
+String.format("%02d",getHourOfDay())+":"
+String.format("%02d",getMinute())
```

You can replace the "E " with what I explained before

Or you can use whatever is currently your timezone... AnyLogic uses your computer timezone in order to know what timezone you are in:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date());
String timezoneCode=cal.getTimeZone().toZoneId().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);
```